# Count API: count query field A with distinct field B value

Tags: elasticsearch

For instance, given this result for a search, reduced to a size of 3 hits for brevity:

```json
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 51812937,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "desc-imunizacao",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7d0ac34a-1d4f-435a-9e5f-6dc2d77bb251-i0b0",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "vacina_descricao_dose": "    2ª Dose",
          "estabelecimento_uf": "BA",
          "document_id": "7d0ac34a-1d4f-435a-9e5f-6dc2d77bb251-i0b0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "desc-imunizacao",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2dc55c6a-5ac1-4550-8990-5ca611808e8a-i0b0",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "vacina_descricao_dose": "    1ª Dose",
          "estabelecimento_uf": "SE",
          "document_id": "2dc55c6a-5ac1-4550-8990-5ca611808e8a-i0b0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "desc-imunizacao",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "d7e9b381-2873-4d0a-8b2d-5fa5034b7a80-i0b0",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "vacina_descricao_dose": "    1ª Dose",
          "estabelecimento_uf": "SE",
          "document_id": "d7e9b381-2873-4d0a-8b2d-5fa5034b7a80-i0b0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I wanted to query for `"estabelecimento_uf": "SE"` and keep only one result for duplicates of `"document_id"`, I would issue:

```json
{
  "_source": ["document_id", "estabelecimento_uf", "vacina_descricao_dose"],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "estabelecimento_uf": {
        "query": "SE"
      }
    }
  },
    "collapse": {
    "field": "document_id",
    "inner_hits": {
    "name": "latest",
      "size": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with [Elasticsearch's Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)? Meaning: count query for **field A** (estabelecimento_uf) and count for unique values of **field B** (document_id), knowing that `document_id` has duplicates of course.

---

This is a public API: https://imunizacao-es.saude.gov.br/_search

This is the authentication:

User: `imunizacao_public`
Pass: `qlto5t&7r_@+#Tlstigi`

Comment: Maybe use aggs?

Comment: Yes, maybe something like [Cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html), I'll try it. I was expecting to use Count API for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation) along with [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html), to get a count of unique document id based on a filter

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filter_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "estabelecimento_uf.keyword": "SE"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_docid": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "document_id.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I know, you **cannot get the count of distinct field values using count API**, you can either use [field collapsing feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) (as done in the question) OR use cardinality aggregation

---

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

```
{
  "vacina_descricao_dose": "    2ª Dose",
  "estabelecimento_uf": "BA",
  "document_id": "7d0ac34a-1d4f-435a-9e5f-6dc2d77bb251-i0b0"
}
{
  "vacina_descricao_dose": "    1ª Dose",
  "estabelecimento_uf": "SE",
  "document_id": "2dc55c6a-5ac1-4550-8990-5ca611808e8a-i0b0"
}
{
  "vacina_descricao_dose": "    1ª Dose",
  "estabelecimento_uf": "SE",
  "document_id": "d7e9b381-2873-4d0a-8b2d-5fa5034b7a80-i0b0"
}
{
  "vacina_descricao_dose": "    1ª Dose",
  "estabelecimento_uf": "SE",
  "document_id": "d7e9b381-2873-4d0a-8b2d-5fa5034b7a80-i0b0"
}
```

**Search Query 1:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "estabelecimento_uf": "SE"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count_doc_id": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "document_id.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "count_doc_id": {
      "value": 2            // note this
    }
  }
```

**Search Query 2:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filter_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "estabelecimento_uf.keyword": "SE"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_docid": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "document_id.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "filter_agg": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "count_docid": {
        "value": 2         // note this
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is what end up doing it, minus the first level `aggs`, using instead "query match" for `estabelecimento_id`. Figured out it wasn't possible with Count API. I forgot to include my answer – thanks.

Comment: I compared my query's result with yours, and when doing a query with (this minified version):  `{"size":0,"query":{"match":{"estabelecimento_uf":"SE"}},"aggs":{"count_doc_id":{"cardinality":{"field":"document_id"}}}}`, I get document count of value 612571, against 613904 from your query. Care to help me understand the difference? Useful: [JSON Beautify tool](https://jsonbeautify.com/). Note: there's no `.keyword` here.

Comment: Actually, I think this isn't one of the answers (the answer you have provided). If I remove the cardinality aggregation, it returns the same result. And I'm certain that there are duplicates for`document_id` for a number of states (estabelecimento_uf), so I think my query works as expected, I'll post it shortly, and hopefully someone will point out the differences or mistakes.

Comment: @RickStanley if you look at this part of documentation --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#use-top-level-query-to-limit-all-aggs, you will find that the query will work in the same way as your minified version

Comment: @RickStanley please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Querying with `.keyword` returns 0, removing it returns a value. I'll have to do some research to judge whether this is the right anwser, because as of now unfortunately I can only guess/aproximate the results with the data at my disposal... In the meantime, I've updated my question to include the public API infos. I'll get back to you, and thank you

Comment: I think it's safe and fair to say that this is the right answer, regardless of my data. But this `.keyword` property left me wondering about it's usage. I'm no Elasticsearch expert - just getting started.

Comment: @RickStanley `.keyword` is used so that a keyword analyzer can be used instead of a standard analyzer. This is  because term query works on exact term matches and text fields are not optimized for aggregation operations